# Prove: Let $g: A\to B$ be an injection and let $D\subset A$. Show that $f(A$ \ $ D) \subset f(A)$ \ $f(D)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

My quesiton reads:

Let $g: A\to B$ be an injection and let $D\subset A$. Show that  $f(A$ \ $ D) \subset f(A)$ \ $f(D)$
Here is my proof so far:

Let $y\in f(A$ \ $D$). Then, there exists an $x\in A$\ $D$ such that $f(x)=y$. I am not sure if this is the right way to continue because I am sure we need to use the injection at this point but I am not too sure.

Comment: it looks like you are assuming the result ... try assuming the contrapositive statement and proceed to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Let $y\in f(A\setminus D$). Then, $y\in f(A)$ and $y\notin f(D)$".

This is not right. If $y\in f(A\setminus D)$ then there exists $x\in A\setminus D$ such that $y = f(x)$.

Now, injectivity of $f$ gives that it can't be true that there exists another $x'\in A$ such that $f(x') = y$.
In particular, do not exist $x'\in D$ such that $f(x') = y$.
Therefore $y\notin f(D)$.

Comment: I am just confused on how you went from having an x' in A to there not being an x' in D.

Comment: Do not exist such $x'$ in $A$ (another than $x$). Since $D\subseteq A$, the same is true for $D$.

Comment: So, since $f$ is an injection, it follows that for x' in A, then f(x') does not equal y?

Comment: What is the definition of a function being injective?

Comment: if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$.

Comment: Which is equivalent to: if $x\neq x'$ then $f(x) \neq f(x')$. Right?